# Page is not refreshing after Delete on React JS (Requires manual reload)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS. I am trying to build a Full Stack CRUD application using React and Spring.

I have configured the Delete REST API (test on Postman) correctly and it works just fine. However, when I click on the delete button on my page the entry is not automatically removed from the page. I have to perform a manual page reload/refresh. Once I reload the page, the entry is shown no more (deleted).

What could possibly be the issue?

**CustomerService.js**

```
deleteCustomer(customerId) {
        return axios.delete(customer_base_url + '/' + customerId);
    }
```

**List Customer Component Constructor**

```
class ListCustomerComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            customers: []
        }

        this.addCustomer = this.addCustomer.bind(this);
        this.editCustomer = this.editCustomer.bind(this);
        this.deleteCustomer = this.deleteCustomer.bind(this);
        this.viewCustomer = this.viewCustomer.bind(this);
    }

    editCustomer(id) {
        this.props.history.push(`/add-customer/${id}`);
    }

    deleteCustomer(id) {
        CustomerService.deleteCustomer(id).then( res => {
            this.setState({customers: this.state.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== id)});
        });
    }
```

**Delete Button**

```
 <button style = {{ marginLeft: "10px"}} onClick = { () => this.deleteCustomer(customers.customerId)} className = "btn btn-danger"> Delete </button>
```

Comment: you can also force a update this.setState({}, (e) => this.forceupdate();}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your delete function I noticed you used `.customerId`.

```
this.deleteCustomer(customers.customerId)}
```

However in your filter function you are checking for `.id`

```
this.state.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== id)}
```

**so your filtering function should probably be**

```
this.state.customers.filter(customer => customer.customerId !== id)}
```

assuming .customerId reflects the customer's unique identifier.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a line in deleteCustomer(id) method -> window.location.reload(false);

```
deleteCustomer(id) {
        CustomerService.deleteCustomer(id).then( res => {
            this.setState({customers: this.state.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== id)});
        });
       window.location.reload(false);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answer given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.